# javascript method array.shift() returning undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this piece of code where I delete the first (or last) element from an array, according to a boolean variable. I do like this:

```
{...
console.log("length before " + waypoints.length)
waypoints = this.deleteWaypoint(waypoints)
console.log("length after " + waypoints.length)
...}

deleteWaypoint(waypoints){
if (this.first){
  this.first = false;
  return waypoints.shift() 
} else {
  this.first = true;
  return waypoints.pop() 
}
}
```

The first log prints that `waypoints` has a certain length, then I call the method to delete elements and when the second log prints is `length after undefined`.  "First" is a global variable initialized to true. 
Why is that?

Comment: As soon as your array is empty, you get undefined, as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift)

Comment: [`Array.prototype.shift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift): _"The `shift()` method removes the first element from an array **and returns that removed element**."_

Comment: Update your return statement to `return waypoints` in `deleteWaypoint`

Comment: Also consider giving us more detail. How does your array look like? [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Andreas Yep, modified now in waypoints.shift(); return waypoints. Thanks. Sorry for the silly question, if you answer I'll give you upvote and correct answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the function as below:

```js
var  waypoints = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0];

var deleteWaypoint = (waypoints)=>{
if (this.first){
  this.first = false;
  waypoints.shift();
  return waypoints
} else {
  this.first = true;
  waypoints.pop()
  return waypoints
}
}

console.log("length before " + waypoints.length)
waypoints = deleteWaypoint(waypoints)
console.log("length after " + waypoints.length)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly fine for me;

```
var deleteWaypoint = function (waypoints) {
  if (this.first) {
    this.first = false;
    waypoints.shift()
  } else {
    this.first = true;
    waypoints.pop()
  }
};

this.first = true
var waypoints = [1,2,3,4,5];
console.log("length before " + waypoints.length);
deleteWaypoint(waypoints)
console.log("length after " + waypoints.length);
```

Array.shift() returns the removed array, in below line copied from code posted in question,

```
waypoints = this.deleteWaypoint(waypoints)
```

the reference of array is getting re-assigned to the removed element which is not array and does not have length property and hence returning undefined

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its correct because in return  `return waypoints.shift()` will return single element which is deleted from array. You can do like this
first,
`waypoints.shift()`
then,
`return waypoints`